# Getting array of Keyframe points in Blender

Tags: python-3.x, blender, blender-2.67

Hi i got a script im working on and its not working out as well as I want it to 
This is what I got so far

```
import bpy
def Key_Frame_Points(): #Gets the key-frame values as an array.

    fcurves = bpy.context.active_object.animation_data.action.fcurves

    for curve in fcurves:

        keyframePoints = fcurves[4].keyframe_points # selects Action channel's axis / attribute

        for keyframe in keyframePoints:

            print('KEY FRAME POINTS ARE  @T ',keyframe.co[0])         
            KEYFRAME_POINTS_ARRAY = keyframe.co[0]

    print(KEYFRAME_POINTS_ARRAY)

Key_Frame_Points()
```

When I run this its printing out all the keyframes on the selected Objects as I wanted it to. But the problem is that I cant for some reason get the Values its printing into a variable. If you run it and check the the System concole. its acting odd.Like as in its printing out the Values of the Keyframed object.But when I ask it to get those values as an array, its just printing out the last frame.

Here is how it looks like briefly

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I think what you want to do is add each `keyframe.co[1]` to an array which means you want to use `KEYFRAME_POINTS_ARRAY.append(keyframe.co[1])` and for that to work you will need to define it as an empty array outside the loop with `KEYFRAME_POINTS_ARRAY = []`

Note that `keyframe.co[0]` is the frame that is keyed while `keyframe.co[1]` is the keyed value at that frame.

Also of note is that you are looping through fcurves but not using each curve.

```
for curve in fcurves:
    keyframePoints = fcurves[4].keyframe_points
```

By using `fcurves[4]` here you are reading the same fcurve every time, you probably meant to use `keyframePoints = curve.keyframe_points`

So I expect you want to have -

```
import bpy

def Key_Frame_Points(): #Gets the key-frame values as an array.
    KEYFRAME_POINTS_ARRAY = []
    fcurves = bpy.context.active_object.animation_data.action.fcurves

    for curve in fcurves:
        keyframePoints = curve.keyframe_points
        for keyframe in keyframePoints:
            print('KEY FRAME POINTS ARE frame:{} value:{}'.format(keyframe.co[0],keyframe.co[1]))
            KEYFRAME_POINTS_ARRAY.append(keyframe.co[1])
    return KEYFRAME_POINTS_ARRAY

print(Key_Frame_Points())
```

You may also be interested to use [`fcurves.find(data_path)`](https://www.blender.org/api/blender_python_api_current/bpy.types.ActionFCurves.html#bpy.types.ActionFCurves.find) to find a specific curve by it's path.

There is also [`fcurve.evaluate(frame)`](https://www.blender.org/api/blender_python_api_current/bpy.types.FCurve.html#bpy.types.FCurve.evaluate) that will give you the curve value at any frame not just the keyed values.

Comment: Thanks but this what I got to work . ts now printing out the Key-frame points I want as an array :P.  Added an Append to the KEYFRAME_POINTS_ARRAY.append( keyframe.co[0]) & Removed the for curve in fcurves:   And it printed out the KEYFRAME_POINTS_ARRAY as a proper array.

Comment: Why `co[1]` is a single value if my data path is `.....rotation_quaternion`?

Comment: @KamilSzot each fcurve holds keyed data for one value. For rotation_quaternion, you will find four fcurves, each with the same data path but a different [`array_index`](https://docs.blender.org/api/current/bpy.types.FCurve.html#bpy.types.FCurve.array_index) value, one for each value in the quat. [This answer](https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/49057/935) should help explain it.